# Is Standard SQL from GBQ comparable to Microsoft SQL and/or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I know there are variations between different SQL types, but I'm trying to understand what is the current standard that everyone is moving to.

For that being said, If I know Standard SQL from GBQ, will I be able to use Microsoft SQL Server and/or MySQL with no problem? or Is it better for me to know Legacy SQL from GBQ in order to work with Microsoft SQL Server and/or MySQL?

Comment: There is no current standard that everyone is moving to. However, the foundations of every SQL implementation are the same, so if you learn one flavour, moving to another is easy.

Comment: @Shadow By a loose definition of "easy" and complicated by "that employee who worked here years ago and fouled everything up with these overly baroque, vendor-specific queries".

Comment: Google's BigQuery "Standard SQL" has nothing to do with "standard SQL" as defined in the ANSI SQL standard.